# Excel: Conditionally formatting each cell based on its own value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column of different percentages, and I want to apply conditional formatting to all of them.

I would like for each cell to be formatted based on its own value, not relative to the remaining cells.

For example, A1 has 50% and A2 has 75%. If I just used the standard conditional formatting (e.g. data bars), then Excel formats them relative to each other, i.e. A1 would have a data bar of 0, and A2 would have a data bar of 100.

However I want A1 to have a data bar of 50, and A2 to have a data bar of 75.

[image: Image displaying issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Created you conditional formating.
2. Edit the formatting by clicking conditional formating -> Manage Rules.
3. Select 'This worksheet' in the top drop down list
4. select the rule and click Edit rule.
5. Select number for minimum and maximum and select a value (In your case 0 and 100)

[image]

Comment: Yes this i Excel 2010.
If the cells is in % format - the same solution works - the values is then set to: 
minimum = 0
maximum = 1